# Camera API. Not saving image

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, camera, fileoutputstream

I'm creating Camera app with Camera API 1. I'm doing that in the fragment. I have FrameLayout where I add the camera, and one button for capture. But after taking a picture the camera not saves the photo. I don't know where's the problem, I'm using camera API the first time. So can you help me to find the solutions?

Other questions did not help me. Their code not worked.

The camera I'm using only in portrait mode. And it manifests, i added the permissions for the camera and write external storage.

I have one class where I'm extending SurfaceView. Let me show you the code.

```
    public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Camera camera;
SurfaceHolder holder;

public ShowCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.camera = camera;
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size mSize = null;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes){
        mSize = size;
    }

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    params.setRotation(90);

    params.setPictureSize(mSize.width, mSize.height);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}
}
```

Ok and here's the fragment for the camera.

```
    public class CameraActivity extends BaseFragment{
View mainView;
FrameLayout cameraLayout;
Camera camera;
ShowCamera showCamera;
ImageButton captureImage;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

    cameraLayout = (FrameLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.cameraContainer);
    captureImage = (ImageButton) mainView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    camera = Camera.open();
    showCamera = new ShowCamera(getActivity(), camera);

    cameraLayout.addView(showCamera);

    capture();

    return mainView;
}

Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
        if(bytes != null){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            if(bitmap != null){
                File file = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)));
                if(!file.isDirectory()){
                    file.mkdir();
                }

                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);

                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();

                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

public void capture(){
    captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(camera != null){
                camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Help me find the solution. Thanks for reading.